# Which way of solving this differential equation is right?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

For my homework assignment I need to solve the following differential equation:

$\dfrac{dT}{dt} = -p(T - T_k)$,

where $T$ stands for the temperature of the pizza, $t$ stands for time and $T_k$ stands for the temperature of the kitchen. They gave me the following information:

1. The initial temperature of the pizza coming out of the freezer at 8pm is $-18^\circ$C.
2. The temperature of the kitchen is $20^\circ$C.
3. $p>0$

First I tried solving the differential equation by substituting $y$ for $T-T_k$ and this gave me the following answer:

$T = T_k + (T(0) - T_k)e^{-pt}$, where I can of course plug in the values of $T(0)$ and $T_k$.

But then I tried solving the differential equation by applying integration from the start, and this gave me the following answer:

$T = ce^{-pt} + T_k$, where I solved $c$ by plugging in $T(0) = -18$ and this gave me a value of $-38$ for $c$.

After this I had to calculate the value of $p$, and I found $p=\log(38) - \log(29)$. For this question it doesn't matter what method I use because they will both give me the same answer $T = T_k - 38 e^{-pt}$, but in the following question they asked me to calculate the temperature of the kitchen in order to defrost the pizza by 9pm. This is where I get confused. When I use my first answer to the differential equation ($T = T_k + (T(0) - T_k)e^{-pt})$ I find a $T_k$ value of $58^\circ$C and when I use my second answer to the differential equation ($T = T_k -38e^{-pt}$) I find a $T_k$ value of $29^\circ$C. Which one (or maybe neither of them) is right and why? What am I doing wrong by solving the differential equation?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that "$-38$" contains/hides an instance of $T_k$.  If you hide that instance, you can't actually solve for $T_k$.  To solve for $T_k$, you need to start with the form that shows all the $T_k$s that are present.
Another way of saying this:

"$T = T_k + (T(0) - T_k)\mathrm{e}^{-pt}$" is the generic equation.  It applies for any choice of $T(0)$ and $T_k$.  When you solved for $c$, you actually solved for "$c$, dependent on $T(0)$ and $T_k$".  If you change either $T(0)$ or $T_k$, you get a different $c$.  That is, particular constants in solutions depend on the parameters present in the equation, so changing the parameters changes the constants (in general -- a careful choice of parameter change would leave $c$ unchanged).

So either use the generic equation, or remember to update your $c$ when you change the parameters.

Comment: That makes sense, so my first solution to the differential equation was right because I didn't hide an instance of $T_k$ in that solution?

Comment: Both solutions are right -- they're actually the same.  One solution makes it easier to change the parameters, so it is more helpful in the next step of the problem.

Comment: But could I also use the second solution to calculate the $T_k$ in order to defrost the pizza by 9pm? Because I would need to find a $c$ for the solution to the differential equation, and I can't use the same $c$ as before.

Comment: @Neri : Notice that when you find $c$, you solve $T(0) = c \cdot 1 + T_k$ for $c$.  We can do this "once and for all": $c = T(0) - T_k$.  Then, if someone changes the parameters $T(0)$ or $T_k$, we can immediately update $c$.  Alternatively, if someone wants to leave $T(0)$ or $T_k$ unspecified, we can replace $c$ with its form in the parameters, $T(0) - T_k$, and proceed with the parameters visible, instead of hiding in $c$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand better now. The only thing I am confused about, what answer do they want when they ask for the solution of the differential equation? I know both answers are the same, but which one is more common to give as an answer to the differential equation?

Comment: @Neri : I would probably provide both the general solution and the solution you get from substituting in the particular values of the parameters.  This gives (first) the version you need in the next part of the problem and (second) the most concise answer for this part of the problem.

Comment: By the way, what about the $p$-value, that doesn't change when I need to calculate $T_k$ right? Because I have to calculate the $p$-value and then later on I need to calculate a $T_k$, but now that I'm thinking about it, I used the same $p$ as I calculated before.

Comment: @Neri : $p$, $T(0)$, and $T_k$ are parameters either provided by the question asker or built into the physical problem.  Unless told otherwise, or the physics forces a relation, these parameters are independent.  When you change the physical situation, the parameters can change.  In this problem, $p$ summarizes the heat transfer between the pizza and the kitchen.  If you put cooling fins on the pizza, $p$ can change.  But as long as you have the same pizza cooling by the same process in the same kitchen, you have the same $p$.

Comment: "But as long as you have the same pizza cooling by the same process in the same kitchen, you have the same ": but it is not the same kitchen anymore since the temperature of the kitchen changed. Doesn't that mean $p$ changes as well?

Comment: @Neri : Did the change of temperature of the kitchen change the mechanism of heat transfer or merely change the (asymptotically) final temperature?

Comment: @Neri : Changes that would invalidate $p$: replace the pizza with an iron ball, put fins on the pizza so the rate of heat transfer between the pizza and the kitchen is changed, replace the air in the kitchen with gaseous or liquid Helium.  All of these change *how* (and thus, at what rate) heat passes between the pizza and the kitchen.  The *quantity* of heat that is transferred is what is controlled by $T(0)$ and $T_k$.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions to the differential equations are correct and should provide the same results. It is obvious that the kitchen temperature of $29 c$ is not realistic so redo the problem with your second formula and get the same result as you have from the first method